# Extract The Second Word In A Line From A Text File

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, cut

I am currently in need to extract the second word (CRISTOBAL) in a line in a text file.

```
                 *   CRISTOBAL  AL042014  08/05/14  12  UTC   *
```

The second word in the line "CRISTOBAL" will vary from day to day so, I just need to find a way to extract JUST the second word/character from the line.

Comment: Which do you need - word or character?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**2nd word**

```
echo '*   CRISTOBAL  AL042014  08/05/14  12  UTC   *' | awk  '{print $2}'
```

will give you `CRISTOBAL`

```
echo 'testing only' | awk  '{print $2}'
```

will give you `only`

You may have to modify this if the structure of the line changes.

**2nd word from lines in a text file**

If your text file contains the following two sentences

```
this is a test
*   CRISTOBAL  AL042014  08/05/14  12  UTC   *
```

running `awk '{print $2}' filename.txt` will return

```
is
CRISTOBAL
```

**2nd character**

```
echo 'testing only' | cut -c 2
```

This will give you `e`, which is the 2nd character, and you may have to modify this so suit your needs also.

Answer (score 2):

In case of sed is needed /only available

```
sed '^ *[^ ]* *\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/' YourFile
```

Take second non blank group (assuming there is at least 1 blank after the word

But I prefer cut for speed (and awk if any manip is needed).

In fact it mainly depend on next action in script (if any).

Answer (score 2):

you can use a shell builtin command:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -f && set +f -- *   CRISTOBAL  AL042014  08/05/14  12  UTC   *
echo $2
```

or better readable using an alias:

```
#!/bin/sh
alias explode='set -f;set +f --'

LINE='*   CRISTOBAL  AL042014  08/05/14  12  UTC   *'
explode $LINE
echo $2
```

The "-f" means:
Disable file name generation (globbing),
so an asterisk will not expand to a filename.
Switching it off and on in one shot sets the default again.
This works in all POSIX shells.

Answer (score -1):

I know it is old but, @NeronLeVelu was hair short of what I needed in a pipe.

```
ip link show wlan0 | grep 'link'| sed 's/^ *[^ ]* *\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/'
```

Was what I used to extract the MAC address. I could not use awk for other reasons.

Comment: I'm glad you could achieve what you wanted, but this doesn't answer OP's question in any way. Consider leaving a comment under @NeronLeVelu's answer instead